# Compare dates in JS with d/m/yyyy format?

Tags: javascript

I'm using this code to compare two dates and it works great for `m/d/yyyy` and `yyyy-m-d` but not `d/m/yyyy` (in FF and in the US at least).

Anyway I can add what formatting I want to use (I need it to work with all three options)? Something like `new Date('14/1/2020', 'd/m/yyyy')` ?

```
var date1 = new Date('14/1/2020');
var date2 = new Date('12/1/2020');
if( date1 > date2 ) { //... }
```

Comment: If the format of your dates is consistent, you're better off splitting it on `/` and creating the `new Date()` using each piece as a separate argument.

Comment: Use moment.js or parse the date yourself - if you know it's an easy format like `d/m/y` then just `.split("/")` and pass the pieces.

Comment: I don't understand how `m/d/yyyy` and `d/m/yyyy` are both valid. For example, how would you know if `1/4/2020` is January 4th or April 1st? If you need all three formats to work, you may need to just split it a different way depending on which format it is.

Comment: @TylerRoper The user picks one of the three under his/her account settings.

Comment: @SeaBass Ah. In that case, you can switch the logic based on the setting. I'll submit an answer.

Comment: Please, for the love of everything good, use [Moment](https://momentjs.com/docs/)

Comment: @reg Thanks, I will on my next project!

Comment: @reg Moment is a great tool and I do highly recommend it, but in the case of `m/d/yyyy` and `d/m/yyyy`, there's no way to distinguish; you'd need to pass the format anyway. Not to mention, it's often better to learn the underlying mechanics and determine *why* a library is necessary, as opposed to becoming completely dependent on it even when you may not need it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest splitting the string and passing the pieces to `new Date()` as individual arguments.

```
const str = '14/1/2020';
const [day,month,year] = str.split('/');
const date = new Date(year, month-1, day);
```

If you need it to support all three formats, you can make it a reusable function and have it accept a `format` argument.

```js
const toDate = (str, format = 'm/d/yyyy') => {
  let month, day, year;

  if (format == 'm/d/yyyy')
    [month, day, year] = str.split("/");
  else if (format == 'd/m/yyyy')
    [day, month, year] = str.split("/");
  else if (format == "yyyy-m-d")
    [year, month, day] = str.split("-");
  else
    throw "Unexpected date format";

  return new Date(year, month-1, day);
}

const str1 = '1/14/2020';
const str2 = '14/1/2020';
const str3 = '2020-1-14';

console.log( toDate(str1) );
console.log( toDate(str2,'d/m/yyyy') );
console.log( toDate(str3,'yyyy-m-d') );
```

Or, for an approach that may be more extensible in the event you need to add formats, you could use an object to define them:

```js
const validFormats = [
  {
    format: 'm/d/yyyy',
    delimiter: '/',
    order: 'mdy'
  },
  {
    format: 'd/m/yyyy',
    delimiter: '/',
    order: 'dmy'
  },
  {
    format: 'yyyy-m-d',
    delimiter: '-',
    order: 'ymd'
  }
];

const toDate = (dateString, format = 'm/d/yyyy') => {
  const validFormat = validFormats.find(d => d.format === format)
  if (!validFormat) throw "Unexpected date format";

  const order     = validFormat.order;
  const dateParts = dateString.split(validFormat.delimiter);
  const year      = dateParts[order.indexOf('y')];
  const month     = dateParts[order.indexOf('m')];
  const day       = dateParts[order.indexOf('d')];
  return new Date(year,month-1,day);
};
 
const str1 = '1/14/2020';
const str2 = '14/1/2020';
const str3 = '2020-1-14';

console.log( toDate(str1) );
console.log( toDate(str2,'d/m/yyyy') );
console.log( toDate(str3,'yyyy-m-d') );
```

Comment: That's awesome, Thanks Tyler! You don't really have to include `m/d/yyyy`, since that is basically going to leave the string untouched right? Edit: Well it's part of your return so I guess you do need it.

Comment: @SeaBass When you pass a string to `new Date()`, you never know what you'll get. So instead, you split it into pieces and pass it as three separate arguments: `new Date(year, month - 1, day)`, and it will *always* work. That's why I split it, regardless of format. I've slightly modified the answer though so that it assumes `'m/d/yyyy'` if you don't pass any format.

Answer (score 0):

You can split them and reorganize the numbers.

```
const dateTokens1 = '14/1/2020'.split('/');
const dateTokens2 = '12/1/2020'.split('/');

//new Date(<year>, <monthIndex>, <day>)
const date1 = new Date(dateTokens1[2], dateTokens1[1]-1, dateTokens1[0]);
const date2 = new Date(dateTokens2[2], dateTokens2[1]-1, dateTokens2[0]);

if (date1 > date2) {...}
```

Comment: Thank you! Do you happen to know if `d/m/yyyy` is the only format out of the three that I need to alter and can I count on `m/d/yyyy` and `yyyy-m-d` working in all browsers and locations? Thanks!

Comment: @SeaBass I'd avoid depending on browser implementation for any date parsing. Using a JS library like [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/) will mitigate these concerns.

Comment: @ajHurliman For the same reason I just mentioned to Seabass, I would avoid constructing a `Date` from a string. Instead, pass each argument separately: `new Date(year, monthIndex, day)`. There is no risk as every browser has the same implementation in this regard.